# ReactJs Beautiful DnD doesn't work on page refresh

Tags: reactjs

I am quite a newbie in developing web app with ReactJs. Currently I tried to develop a drag and drop list item to re-order the items in the list.

I copied the codes identically from here:
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-beautiful-dnd-tutorial-forked-sb2bdi

The only changes I made are:

1. I change the `innerRef={provided.innerRef}` to `ref={provided.innerRef}` in both `column.js` and `task.js`
2. I create a new component called `TestDraggable.js` instead of directly rendering the list in `index.js`

here is my TestDraggable code:

```
import React from 'react'
import { DragDropContext } from 'react-beautiful-dnd'
import styled from 'styled-components'
import Column from './column'
import initialData from './initial-data'

const Container = styled.div`
  display: flex;
`

class TestDraggable extends React.Component {
  state = initialData

  onDragEnd = (result) => {
    const { destination, source, draggableId } = result

    if (!destination) {
      return
    }

    if (
      destination.droppableId === source.droppableId &&
      destination.index === source.index
    ) {
      return
    }

    const start = this.state.columns[source.droppableId]
    const finish = this.state.columns[destination.droppableId]

    if (start === finish) {
      const newTaskIds = Array.from(start.taskIds)
      newTaskIds.splice(source.index, 1)
      newTaskIds.splice(destination.index, 0, draggableId)

      const newColumn = {
        ...start,
        taskIds: newTaskIds
      }

      const newState = {
        ...this.state,
        columns: {
          ...this.state.columns,
          [newColumn.id]: newColumn
        }
      }

      this.setState(newState)
      return
    }

    // Moving from one list to another
    const startTaskIds = Array.from(start.taskIds)
    startTaskIds.splice(source.index, 1)
    const newStart = {
      ...start,
      taskIds: startTaskIds
    }

    const finishTaskIds = Array.from(finish.taskIds)
    finishTaskIds.splice(destination.index, 0, draggableId)
    const newFinish = {
      ...finish,
      taskIds: finishTaskIds
    }

    const newState = {
      ...this.state,
      columns: {
        ...this.state.columns,
        [newStart.id]: newStart,
        [newFinish.id]: newFinish
      }
    }
    this.setState(newState)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <DragDropContext onDragEnd={this.onDragEnd}>
        <Container>
          {this.state.columnOrder.map((columnId) => {
            const column = this.state.columns[columnId]
            const tasks = column.taskIds.map(
              (taskId) => this.state.tasks[taskId]
            )

            return (
              <Column key={column.id} column={column} tasks={tasks} />
            )
          })}
        </Container>
      </DragDropContext>
    )
  }
}

export default TestDraggable
```

My `column.js` code:

```
import React from "react"
import styled from "styled-components"
import Task from "./task"
import { Droppable } from "react-beautiful-dnd"

const Container = styled.div`
  margin: 8px;
  border: 1px solid lightgrey;
  border-radius: 2px;
  width: 220px;

  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
`
const Title = styled.h3`
  padding: 8px;
`
const TaskList = styled.div`
  padding: 8px;
  transition: background-color 0.2s ease;
  background-color: ${(props) => (props.isDraggingOver ? "skyblue" : "white")}
  flex-grow: 1;
  min-height: 100px;
`

export default class Column extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Container>
        <Title>{this.props.column.title}</Title>
        <Droppable droppableId={this.props.column.id} type="TASK">
          {(provided, snapshot) => (
            <TaskList
              ref={provided.innerRef}
              {...provided.droppableProps}
              isDraggingOver={snapshot.isDraggingOver}
            >
              {this.props.tasks.map((task, index) => (
                <Task key={task.id} task={task} index={index} />
              ))}
              {provided.placeholder}
              
            </TaskList>
          )}
        </Droppable>
      </Container>
    )
  }
}
```

The drag and drop works, but when I refresh the page in the browser, the drag and drop won't work anymore.

If I add a new line to `column.js` and ctrl + S the file, the drag and drop works again. But if I simply ctrl + S without any changes, then it won't work.

May I know what possibly be the cause here?

Comment: Having the same issue. Were you able to fix it ? 
DnD works after hot reload, but doesn't on first load.